# Drupal View: show ALL users with node count of a content type

Tags: views, 10

I need to display a list of users with a count of nodes they created of a particular type (say Article) like follows. I could almost achieve that using "Views Aggregation" by the following steps,

1. Created a user view.
2. Added a relationship to "User: Content Authored"

Fields:

[image: Added fields "User : Name"(Group results and "Content: ID"]

3. Enabled Aggregation
4. Set the Content: ID field's aggregation settings to COUNT

| User Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Krishna | 0 |
| Mohan | 2 |

But when I applied a filter by content type (Group results together) the record with 0 count is disappearing (Example : krishna record from the above table)

I want to filter this view to display data with the 'X' content type results. This means that users with no nodes should have the count displayed as 0, as shown in the above example

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!